# How do I add a default filter in a Dynamics AX 2012 R3 List Page

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

For example: in the SalesTableListPage I would like to apply a filter automatically when the form opens. I would like this filter to appear in the standard filter area, as shown below. And I need this filter to be done from the AOT, so that the users will not need to implement this within the Rich Client themselves.

I can workaround this by making an additional menu item, as in SalesTableListPageOpen. But this option would not allow a user to switch over to invoiced or canceled sales.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Filter Location]

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done, it is not a supported scenario. You can change the  query range, but it will not give the hint in the user interface.

Comment: While the first part is correct, I did find something in my case that could be used for a workaround. If I modify a query range and add it's associated field onto the List Page, then the user will see the filter above the affected column.

For example: if I add a query range of "Open Order" on SalesTable.SalesStatus for SalesTableListPage, the user will see the filter above the Sales Status field. The user could then also change the filter, by modifying the text and pressing enter. 

So while this isn't what I was looking for in the question, this is the closest solution that I have seen